# Power iteration for eigenvectors decomposition - python

Tags: python, eigenvector, eigenvalue

All I found about power method, was for the largest/smallest eigenvectors and eigenvalues. How can I compute all eigenvectors of a matrix ?

specifically, I'm trying to do that in python, but any resource regarding how to do that would be of great help.

Comment: Numpy has this built in: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html

Comment: I'm looking to do that with the power method iteration

Comment: Anyways. got it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114777/approximate-the-second-largest-eigenvalue-and-corresponding-eigenvector-given